# Set bits combined with exponential modular arithmetics

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, modular-arithmetic, modulo

[image: problem description]

I got this question yesterday in a challenge. I thought I had coded it correctly and my sample test case was passed. However not even a single test case passed at the backend. Here is my code. Please, someone, help me out. The challenge is over for me and so I can't submit it further. But I want to learn from my mistakes. Thanks.

```
  import java.io.*;
//import java.util.*;


public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(System.out);
         int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
         String[] arr_a = br.readLine().split(" ");
         int[] a = new int[n];
         for(int i_a=0; i_a<arr_a.length; i_a++)
         {
            a[i_a] = Integer.parseInt(arr_a[i_a]);
         }

         long out_ = solve(a);
         System.out.println(out_);

         wr.close();
         br.close();
    }
    static long solve(int[] a){
        // Write your code here
        long sum = 0l;
        long MAX = 10000000011l;
        long i = 1l;
        for(int x : a) {
            long count = 0;
            while(x>0) {
                x &= (x-1l);
                count++;
            }
            long res = 1l;
            long temp = i;
            count = count % MAX;
            while(temp > 0) {
                if((temp & 1l) == 1l) {
                    res = (res * count) % MAX;
                }
                temp = temp >> 1l;
                count = ((count % MAX) * (count % MAX)) % MAX;

            }

            long t =((sum%MAX) + (res % MAX))%MAX;
            sum = t;
            i++;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems ok. The only problem I see is `count*count` which might exceed `long` limit.

Comment: How to resolve? Like I have to do ((count%max)×(count%max))%max ?

Comment: Try `BigInteger`.

Comment: [Inman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504754/lnman) . No, Buddy, This Idea is not working either.

Comment: Is it failing because of time or because of giving the wrong answer?

Comment: [samgak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696391/samgak) wrong ans.

Comment: Provide sample test case or link to the site.

Comment: @Inman [this is link](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/hiring/peoplestrong-java-hiring-challenge/algorithm/killjee-and-easy-problem-ef205c19/)

Comment: What is the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: @nglee I have used [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/) post's algorithm. I have used while loop for calculating the x^y mod p

Comment: Can't access this link.

Comment: @Inman the challenge is over that's why. The link is same but the question is not opening.

Comment: could you show your `BigInteger` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit strange that "not even a single test case passed", but the only error I see is your [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) part.

All your numbers are less than `10^10 + 11`, but this constant has more than 32 bits, and when you multiply, you get an overflow sometimes (because `long` is a 64-bit signed integer).

This can be fixed by several approaches:

1. `(a*b) % M` operation can be done with the algorithm that is similar to your "exponentiation by squaring" implementation. You just need to replace all multiplications with additions. As a result, multiplication is replaced with `O(log(n))` additions and 'multiplying by 2' operations. Sample implementation:

   ```
   static long multiply(long a, long b, long M) {
       long res = 0;
       long d = a % M;

       while (b > 0) {
           if ((b & 1) == 1) {
               res = (res + d) % M;
           }

           b >>= 1;
           d = (d + d) % M;
       }
       return res;
   }
   ```
2. You can just cache `b^i % M` numbers for previously computed steps. For every number of set bits (there are not so many of them), you can save previously computed values and `last(b)` - the last `i` when `a[i]` had `b` set bits. Then just compute the new value with a linear loop from `last(b) + 1` till current index `i`.
3. Use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for multiplications.

Comment: [Dale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759200/dale) I got your point but now while implementing your method in f(n) = 0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 .... + n ^ n . f(n) mod m where n <= 10^9 & m <= 10 ^ 3. I am getting time limit exceeded. Help.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore, you need this method when you're multiplying numbers that are bigger than `2^31` (as in the question above). If you have `n <= 10^9`, you don't need it.

Comment: [Dale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759200/dale) I have tried above method with or without your multiply method as well as used BigInteger for the question f(n) % m. where f(n) = 0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 .... but all I got is TLE. Why? isn't this the fast algo? Please help me out.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore, this is a completely different task, why don't you create a new question? I believe you don't need any approaches from my answer to solve this task. And take attention to the fact that `m` is relatively small.